# When will this break?

Tags: trigger

I've got a trigger that originally just converted the members of a Campaign into a text string in order to create a "CC List" for mailmerges.  Worked brilliantly.  However, over time I've been asked to add bits and pieces, and now the trigger is more of a 'class' than just a trigger.  Other than needed to now make this a class, what other risks can you see in what the code is trying to do?  Basically, what is going to cause this to break?  Also, any best practice suggestions regarding how this is currently written?

```
trigger UpdateQuarterlyLetterCampaign on CampaignMember (after insert, after update) {
    list<campaignMember> newMember = trigger.new;
    list<campaignMember> allMembers = new list<campaignMember>();
    set<id> campID = new set<ID>();
    campaign thisCampaign;
    string ccText = '';



for (campaignmember cmCheck: newMember){
    campID.add(cmCheck.CampaignId);
}

if(campID.size() != 1){
    }
else{
    thisCampaign = [select id, name, cc_list__c, recordtypeid, recordtype.name from campaign where id in :campID ];
    allMembers = [select id, firstname, lastname, cc_order__c, CompanyOrAccount from campaignMember where campaignid in :campID and cc_order__c <> 'Primary' and cc_order__c <> '' order by cc_order__c];
    system.debug('AllMembers is this big:'+allMembers.size());
        if(allMembers.size() > 15){
            thisCampaign.cc_list__c = 'A maximum of 15 CC names can be added to this Campaign';
            }
        else{
            if(thisCampaign.recordtype.name == 'Asset Management Quarterly Letter'){
                for(campaignmember am: allMembers){
                ccText = ccText + am.FirstName +' '+ am.lastname +' - '+ am.CompanyOrAccount +'\r\n';
                thisCampaign.cc_list__c = ccText;
                }
            }   
        }
}
update thisCampaign;
}
```

Trigger code updated to "update outside of loop"
Another update to pull SOQL out of loop.

Comment: Apart from the SOQL queries and DML operations in the for loop ? :P

Comment: Didn't realize the Update was in the loops.  Thanks.  Trying to get the SOQL out now as well.

Comment: Followup:  for the thisCampaign statement, how would I get the pertinent information from/about the Campaign related to the Member without querying within the loop?

Comment: Have a look at this documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com You would need to do a subquery and merge the two queries into one and select parent and child records at the same time based on campaign id. Then do the for loop

Comment: Updated code to move updates and soql, but still unsure.  Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some simplifications you can do and also much fewer variable names

```
trigger UpdateQuarterlyLetterCampaign on CampaignMember (after insert, after update) {

    set<ID> cIdSet = new set<ID> ();  // campaigns in the triggered CampaignMembers
    for (CampaignMember cm: Trigger.new)
        cIdSet.add(cm.campaignId);

    // get all campaigns and their CampaignMembers in the trigger list
    map<ID,Campaign> cIdToCampaignMap = new map<ID,Campaign> (
                                            [select id, recordType.name
                                              (select id, firstName, lastName, companyOrAccount 
                                                 from CampaignMember
                                                 where cc_order__c <> 'Primary' and
                                                        cc_order__c <> ''
                                                )
                                              from Campaign
                                              where id IN :cIdSet]);
    for (Campaign c: cIdToCampaignMap.values()) {
        if (c.campaignMembers.size() > 15)
            c.cc_list__c = 'Max 15 cc';
        else {
            c.cc_list__c = '';
            for (CampaignMember cm : c.campaignMembers)
                c.cc_list__c += c.recordType.name = 'Asset Mgt...'
                                    ? cm.firstName + ' ' + cc.lastName + ' ' + cc.companyOrAccount + '/r/n'
                                    : '';
        }
    }
    update cIdToCampaignMap.values();
}
```

Your business logic is a bit weird in that you check for 15+ members of any recordtype and decide that is too many but you appear to only really care about 15 asset mgt members. I'll leave that change to you (hint, extend the soql where clause).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment?  I'm checking that there aren't more than 15 CampaignMembers, and that the Campaign.Recordtype is "Asset Mgmt"  Am I mis-reading what I wrote?  Basically, the code should only run if the member is being added to a specific Campaign record type, and if there are fewer than 15 members in the campaign.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: HomerJ -- Maybe I misunderstood -- but, it seems like you should be checking that there are fewer than 15 Asset Mgt campaign Members, not fewer than 15 total campaign members.  Suppose campaign has 60 members but only 5 are asset mgt members, then you won't build any cc list.

Comment: Right, I understand.  The campaign record type is only available to the Asset Management business (by profile) and they only have access to their own contacts.  So there should never be a time when non-AM members are added.  However, you're correct in your assessment.  There should NEVER be more than 15 members of any type in one of these campaigns, so it should fail, regardless of the type of member.

Comment: so -- are you all set now? LMK if any other issues

Comment: Thanks all.  Ended up converting to a Trigger/Class/Testclass arch after realizing the testing needed to be more robust.  Used all the above to clean up the trigger.